# How to determine if daylight savings time is in effect?

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a isDST function for a time.Time, however I'm not sure how to go about it. The problem is that the Location type in the time package does not export the zone information (which contains the isDST bool)

See below extract. Is there anyway to get this information?

```
// A Location maps time instants to the zone in use at that time.
// Typically, the Location represents the collection of time offsets
// in use in a geographical area. For many Locations the time offset varies
// depending on whether daylight savings time is in use at the time instant.
type Location struct {
    name string
    zone []zone
    tx   []zoneTrans

    // The tzdata information can be followed by a string that describes
    // how to handle DST transitions not recorded in zoneTrans.
    // The format is the TZ environment variable without a colon; see
    // https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html.
    // Example string, for America/Los_Angeles: PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
    extend string

    // Most lookups will be for the current time.
    // To avoid the binary search through tx, keep a
    // static one-element cache that gives the correct
    // zone for the time when the Location was created.
    // if cacheStart <= t < cacheEnd,
    // lookup can return cacheZone.
    // The units for cacheStart and cacheEnd are seconds
    // since January 1, 1970 UTC, to match the argument
    // to lookup.
    cacheStart int64
    cacheEnd   int64
    cacheZone  *zone
}

// A zone represents a single time zone such as CET.
type zone struct {
    name   string // abbreviated name, "CET"
    offset int    // seconds east of UTC
    isDST  bool   // is this zone Daylight Savings Time?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect daylight saving time in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901906/detect-daylight-saving-time-in-bash)

Comment: You can try the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53051355